# How to get data from a pie chart in Excel 2003?

Tags: ocr, excel-2003, pie-chart, autoit

This question is easy to answer, but not in my case.

I have a .xls Excelsheet with automatically generated charts. Now, I need the `(source-)data` on which the chart is based. The problem is that these `(source-)data` are no longer available in the .xls file.

Any ideas how I can get the data?

I thought of AutoIt or an OCR software. However, I have no experience with it (OCR).

Answer (score 0):

There is a UDF to control excel with AutoIt, but since you have no experience with it, I suggest downloading the [editor](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/) and getting to know the basics of AutoIt.

Once you've downloaded the editor you can go [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/21048-welcome-to-autoit-1-2-3/) to learn the basics of the capabilities of AutoIt.

After that, you can use this [UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/34302-yet-another-excelcom-udf/) to help with excel automation and other tasks.

Comment: I know the basics of AutoIT. But how this UDF can help me to get the data of a pie chart? Cant find a function for this.

Comment: wouldn't the data from the pie chart be in cells that make up the pie chart? If not, I would think there has got to be some way to convert the pie chart within excel back into your source data.

Comment: See above: data are no longer available = no data in cells. How can i convert a chart into data?

Comment: Was the chart made in excel 2003?

Comment: Yes, the chart was made in excel03.

Comment: Is this pie chart in a workbook by chance? I haven't had any experience using this UDF, but if I know the steps you have taken to make the pie chart and then make the data unavailable I'm hoping I can try and recreate.